# Is n operations of O(1) average time each considered O(n) in average?

Tags: data-structures, hash, language-agnostic, time-complexity

I'm studying to data structures exam and I'm trying to solve this question:

> given an array of n numbers and a number Z, find x,y such as x+y=Z , in O(n) average time.

My suggestion is move the array's content to a hash table, and using open addressing do the following:

For each number A[i] search for Z-A[i] in the hash table (O(1) in average for each operation.) Worst case you'll perform n searches, O(1) average time each, that's O(n) in average.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Yup. More formally, you need to explain why converting the array to the hash table can be done in O(n) time as well.

Comment: that's what open addressing does

Comment: @AlaaM. yup, but if you're actually trying to prove it you have to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are traversing all your array the second time, yes that is O(n) * O(1) (and not O(n)+O(1) as previously stated from me) (for hash lookup in average time), so you are talking about an algorithm of O(n) complexity .

Comment: i'm doing the lookup maximum n times. then it's O(n)*O(1) and not O(n) + O(1)